# Rename built-in python methods like replace()

Tags: python, replace, module

I am writing a python script that uses the `string.replace()` method a lot. I know that if I was importing a python method from a module I could change its name using `from` like so:

```
from time import sleep as x
```

And then, `x(5)` would be the same as `time.sleep(5)`. But how can I do that to the replace() function? It isn't from any external module, and I have tried to do this:

```
x = replace()
```

But it doesn't work. It says `NameError: name 'replace' is not defined`.

So please tell me how to "rename" the built-in replace function.

Comment: Why would you use `string.replace` instead of the method `replace` on `str` objects? Unless you're writing Python 1.5…

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the use of replace in contexts like: `s = "hello world"; s = s.replace('hello', 'goodbye')`

Comment: The str class is a built-in extension, so you can't edit its namespace. You can, however, subclass it and define functionality however you like in the derived class.

Answer (score 5):

First, you should almost never be using [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions). As the docs say:

> The following list of functions are also defined as methods of string and Unicode objects; see section *String Methods* for more information on those. You should consider these functions as deprecated…

Second, this is wrong for two separate reasons:

```
x = replace()
```

First, there is no builtin named `replace`, and there's no global in your module named `replace` either. If you did `from string import *` or `from string import replace`, then you wouldn't get this error—but if you were doing that, you could just do `from string import replace as x`, exactly as you're already doing for `time.sleep`.

Second, those parentheses mean that you're calling the function, and assigning its return value to `x`, not using the function itself as a value.

---

So, I think what you want is this:

```
x = str.replace
```

That's accessing the `replace` method on `str` objects, and storing it in `x`. An "unbound method" like this can be called by passing an instance of `str` (that is, any normal string) as the first argument. So:

```
x(my_string, ' ', '_')
```

---

If you want to add the name `x` as a method on the `str` class itself, what you want is called "monkeypatching", and normally, it's very simple:

```
str.x = str.replace
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with most of the built-in types, at least in CPython; you'll get an error like this:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

You could of course create your own subclass of `str`, and use that all over the place instead of `str`… but that won't help with string literals, strings you get back from other functions, etc., unless you wrap them explicitly. And I'm not sure it's worth the effort. But if you want to:

```
class s(str):
    x = str.replace
```

Now you can do this:

```
z = s(function_returning_a_string())
z = z.x(' ', '_')
```

But notice that at the end, `z` is back to being a `str` rather than an `s`, so if you want to keep using `x`, you have to do this:

```
z = s(z.x(' ', '_'))
```

… and at a certain point, even if you're saving a few keystrokes, you're not saving nearly enough for the cost in readabiity and idiomaticitalnessity.

Comment: " `str.x = str.replace`  
Unfortunately, it doesn't work with most of the built-in types,..."  
That statement was the best help on this issue. It sure is easy to monkey patch if it is not built-in. But it seems that when I really want to do this, it is usually a built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do what you want:

```
a = 'asdf'

a_replace = a.replace
```

Now `a_replace` is a bound method object that does `a.replace(whatever)` when you call `a_replace(whatever)`. You can also do

```
my_replace = str.replace

my_replace('asdf', 'a', 'f') # calls 'asdf'.replace('a', 'f')
```

However, what you probably want is

```
some_magic()
'asdf'.my_replace('a', 'f') # calls 'asdf'.replace('a', 'f')
```

and that's not possible without messing with things you're really not supposed to mess with:

```
# Awful hack. Last resort only.
import gc
for referrer in gc.get_referrers(str.replace):
    if type(referrer) is dict and str.__dict__ in gc.get_referrers(referrer):
        # Almost certainly the dict behind str's dictproxy.
        referrer['my_replace'] = str.replace
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely NOT advisable to do in any of your projects. But this is possible:
We could do some metahacking - replacing the builtin str with our custom one

```
class myStr(str):
    def def my_replace(self, __old, __new, __count):
        return self.replace(__old, __new, __count)

__builtins__.__dict__['str'] = myStr
```

Now the all usages of str are replaced with our implementation. You can add or change whatever you want. In our case both replace methods will work, one inherited from str and one created by us:

```
print('dsadas'.replace('d', '_'))
>>> _sa_as
print('dsadas'.my_replace('d', '_'))
>>> _sa_as
```

But remember this is fun, but using those technics in real project could ruin a lot of other functionality.

Comment: Really like this solution, will implement in my production code. It will just be mentioned in the documentation of the program and I'll be good!